# Разметка изображений в WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется 10 изображений в окне без рамки WPF формы. Как мне их разместить так, чтобы можно было из другой формы растягивать сразу все изображения сохраняя их пропорции? Во второй форме два слайдера, которыми растягиваем первую форму и что бы изображения так же растягивались?

Comment: У класса `Image` есть свойство `Stretch`, когда это свойство установлено в значение `Uniform` размер изображения меняется в соответствии с размерами контейнера, но исходные пропорции сохраняются.

Comment: Области, в которых размещаются ваши 10 изображений одинаковые по размеру должны быть?

Comment: Да, одинаковые.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так:

1) Для отображения списка картинок воспользуемся элементом `ListBox`.
2) Чтобы область просмотра каждой картинки была одинаковой, у элемента `ListBox` переопределяем `ItemsPanel` и в качестве панели устанавливаем `UniformGrid`.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

3) Далее определяем шаблон для отображения каждого элемента списка. Так как нам нужно отображать картинки, используем элемент `Image`. Кроме того, чтобы они растягивались пропорционально, создаем стиль для них в ресурсах окна.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- Что бы картинки растягивались пропорционально -->
    <Style x:Key="ImageStyle" 
           TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
                <Image Source="{Binding Path}"
                               Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

4) Чтобы картинки занимали всю выделенную для них область, устанавливаем свойства `ListBox.HorizontalContentAlignment` и `ListBox.VerticalContentAlignment` в значение `Stretch`, а также отключаем вертикальный и горизонтальный ScrollBar.

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
</ListBox>
```

5) Собираем то что сделали вместе.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- Что бы картинки растягивались пропорционально -->
        <Style x:Key="ImageStyle" 
               TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path}"
                               Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
       </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

Далее во ViewModel заполняем нашу коллекцию картинок данными.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyImg> Images { get; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Images = new ObservableCollection<MyImg>();

        // Заполняем данными коллекцию...
    }
}

// Класс, который представляет нашу картинку.
public class MyImg
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: я сделал чуть проще, добавив изображения через ресурсы.

<Image x:Name="Image1" Source="Resources/Q1.png"></Image>.

мне просто нужно чтобы при определенных условиях изображения менялись.

image1.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/Q2.png"));.

что-то типа того, надеюсь будет работать...

Comment: @NochnoeRandevu в вашем  случае количество картинок жестко определено?

Comment: десять картинок в два столбца, форма будет "прокликиваемой" внутрь, чтобы клики уходили в окно за формой, ну и прозрачной, кроме картинок

Comment: @NochnoeRandevu ну общую идею как сделать растягивание и одинаковую ширину вы можете взять из этого примера.

Comment: единственное - не могу понять как можно с помощью двух трекбаров на второй форме изменять положение первой WPF формы?

Comment: вторая - winforms

Comment: то бишь, проблема была создать WPF окно в winform приложении, а на оборот отлично создается... но как из winform изменить положение wpf окна?

Comment: @NochnoeRandevu а зачем такой хак нужен?

Comment: wpf окно (главное приложение) будет оверлеем без границ, возможности изменять размер и перетаскивать его... но хочу все это изменять с помощью треков (слайдеров) на winform во втором окне

Comment: wpf окно прокликивается внутрь (все клики уходят за это окно), по этому изменять его можно только из другой формы

Comment: есть идеи как можно это организовать? то есть 4 трека на winforme... первый - положение wpf формы по х, второй по y, третий - прозрачность, 4 - размер... ну и отдельная кнопка для hide, show для показа WPF (основной) формы

Comment: надеюсь на тебя

Comment: @NochnoeRandevu зачем усложнять жизнь, почему не сделать все на WPF?